# Meaning of $f$ Extends to A Meromorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

What does it mean by saying that "$g$ extends to a meromorphic function $f$"?

Does it means there another function $f$ which has a function $g$  as a term, (i.e., $\zeta(s)$ is present in that function) and that function is holomorphic - means it is complex differentiable, i.e.,   has derivative on complex plane - except some point(s)?

Is above understanding correct?

The source of the above question is given below-
[image]

Comment: Extension (or continuation) of a function $g:A\to B$ is when you find a function $f:C\to B$ with $C\supset A$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in A$. When adjectives are added to the name, like *analytic*, or *meromorphic*, or *continuous*, or *bounded*, it means that the extension is done such that $f$ has those extra properties.

Comment: It means that you have another analytic function $g$ and there is an open set where it is equal to $f$. For example : $f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 0} z^k$ for $|z| < 1$ and $g(z)=\frac1{1-z}$ for $z\ne 1$. **The analytic continuation if it exists is unique**. Meromorphic extension is the same except there may be a few poles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "function", by definition, has three ingredients: a "domain of definition" $X$, a "domain of value" $Y$, and a rule that assigns to each $x\in X$ an element $y \in Y$.

When we say "$g$ extends to $f$", it basically means that $g$ is *a priori* defined only on a smaller set $X$ and $f$ is defined on a superset $X'$ containing $X$, such that the restriction of $f$ to $X$ coincides with $g$.

In your case, I guess $\Phi(s)$ is originally only defined for $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 1$, and then it extends to $\operatorname{Re}(s) > \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be open subsets of $\mathbb C$, with $A\subset B$, and let $f\colon A\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ be a holomorphic function. We say that $f$ extends to a meromorphic function on $B$ if there is a meromorphic function $g\colon B\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ such that $g|_A=f$ (or, in other words, $(\forall z\in A):g(z)=f(z)$).

Note that, strictly speaking, the domain of $g$ doesn't have to be $B$. It is a subset $D_g$ of $B$ such that each $z_0\in B\setminus D_g$ is a pole of $g$.